# $\int_{y=0}^{y=2} \int_{x= y}^{x=\sqrt{8-y^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}dxdy$ using double integration in polar coordinates.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

$\int_{y=0}^{y=2} \int_{x= y}^{x=\sqrt{8-y^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}dxdy$ using double integration in polar coordinates.

My attempt:

Let $x=rcos(\theta),y=rsin(\theta)$

Then the integration becomes

$\int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/4} \int_{r=0}^{2\sqrt{2}} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} drd\theta=4\pi$

However the answer is $\frac{(3-\sqrt{5})\pi}{2}$

Comment: The integral you write there is equal to $\pi/2$ instead of $4 \pi$, I believe. Still not equal to the solution.

Comment: What do I do? Is the limit calculation not okay?

Comment: I believe the limits are ok, you are integrating over a slice of pizza. But the integral you compute has an algebra mistake (I did it manually but let me know if you don't get it by redoing it) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B%5Ctheta+%3D+0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F4%7D+%5Cint_%7Br%3D0%7D%5E%7B2%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D+%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Br%5E2%2B1%7D%7D+drd%5Ctheta

Comment: The integral in the title is equal to $\pi/2$. What is the original problem whose supposed answer is $\frac{(3-\sqrt{5})\pi}{2}$?